# Set HttpOnly and Cookie to secure

Tags: nginx, flask

[image]

I tried adding `proxy_cookie_path / "/; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=strict";` under /location{} in nginx.conf, however it still shows unsecured.

Do I need to do anything from application side, in my case...Flask?